# WebJars containing lodash.d.ts

Tags: typescript, lodash, webjars

My web application is webjar based and uses typescript. I am looking to add Lodash to my application, unfortunately I can't find any webjars containing lodash.d.ts. I do have a typings repository containing a browser.d.ts file but I can't reference a js file there (and my webjars only provides some lodash.js files).

Is there any webjar containing lodash.d.ts ?

Answer (score 1):

It is in the DefinitelyTyped NPM WebJar:

```
GroupId: org.webjars.npm
ArtifactId: github-com-DefinitelyTyped-DefinitelyTyped
Version: 0.0.1
```

Comment: Is there a way to only select lodash or do I have to take the full git repo ?

Comment: Unfortunately you have to take the full repo with that library.

Comment: More libraries are now distributed with type definitions. How can one use those type definition in Play project?

1. The WebJars are downloaded AFTER a build has finished.
2. The downloaded WebJars are placed under 'target' folder.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean and this probably isn't the best place to discuss this.  How about we continue the conversation at: https://gitter.im/webjars/webjars